# DWScript: Add an new array definition to a dwsUnit at runtime

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, dwscript

What is the method, using Delphi XE2, to call to add Array definition to a `dwsUnit` component at runtime?

`MyDwsUnit.Arrays.Add` returns a `TCollectionItem`, not `TdwsArray`, while adding an array definition at design time adds a `TdwsArray` instance!.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default TCollection.Add method returns a TCollectionItem, even though it's actually an instance of whatever items the collections manages (this isn't specific to DWScript, it's a Delphi VCL thing).

To simplify that, most subclassed collections in DWScript now reintroduce an Add method that will wrap the default one with a cast, so you don't have to do the cast manually. So chances are you're on older version of DWScript.

If you don't want to update, you can just use

```
(MyDwsUnit.Arrays.Add as TdwsArray)
```

instead.

Comment: Thank you Eric. You are right, i am on V2.2 (sorry i forget to mention this). Will update once V2.3 is stable. i used :var
  ArrayVar:TdwsArray;
begin
  ArrayVar := TdwsArray.Create(FMainUnit.Arrays); and it works. thanks again.